# How can i print the page as it is

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd have added a button in my page include `onsubmit="return window.print()"` but when i click on it, A print window dialog appears in printing view my page colors turns black all styles gone. How can i print the page as it is with style with same colors

Comment: Do you mean that background-colors have been removed? If so, that's an option (print with, or without, background-colors/background-images) only available to your users (via their browser's print settings). Don't attempt to force your users to waste their money on printer ink, just because you'd like your page to stay pretty. It's their money, their call.

Comment: Most print styles turn all the text black and remove a lot of formatting. You can make your own print css file, google it up.

Comment: i had Google nothing found, @DavidThomas Yes all of my page formation removes background turn black..

Comment: It could be that your browser thinks the printer doesn’t support color and thus desaturates the whole page.

Comment: No @icktoofay. Its not the solution

Answer (score 2):

It happens when your css is not optimized for print media. You can include your css in below style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="mystyle.css">
```

And remember that background images not rendered in print.

Reference article : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@media print` to style your pages for printing.

Example in CSS file:

```
@media print {//styles
}
```

Also here is a link to a starter guide of this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Link a stylesheet at the bottom of your head (So that it is the primary one).

In that stylesheet put in the following media query

```
@media print
{
    put styles here
}
```

Whatever you put in the query will be used in printing.

Comment: This is not how it works, my style sheet is upto 6,000 lines i can't modify all of them again in media query.. please ans accurate  or comment the suggestion

Comment: Actually, that is how it works - or partially anyway. Another option would be: You add a new stylesheet (below all the others : cascading) and modify the styles (only those) you need modified for printing. Beware though that the result will depend not only on the styles you select, but also on the browsers interpretation. I suggest you take a look at the link two of the answers already gave.

Comment: Why dont you just copy and paste your stylesheet in to that media query?